# Merging two dataframes on one matching variable and retaining only one value for other disjoint variables

Tags: r, merge

I have two dataframes I need to merge. The dataframes share all of the same columns. I am merging based on one shared variable, worker_ID. However, the other variables are often disjoint: one dataframe will have an "NA" and the other will have another value for a given variable. How can I merge in such a way that the output only retains the non-NA value?

```
x = worker_ID Var_1 Var_2 Var_3
    1         33    NA    NA
    2         NA    46    NA

y = worker_ID Var_1 Var_2 Var_3
    1         NA    75    NA
    2         NA    NA    66

z <- merge(x,y,by="worker_ID", all = TRUE)
```

This method does not work because instead of my desired output, z, I get a dataframe with two columns for each variable (one for the value of the variable in x and another for y). My desired output is z.

```
z = worker_ID Var_1 Var_2 Var_3
    1         33    75    NA
    2         NA    46    66
```

How can I tell R to let any non-NA entries supersede NA ones?

Comment: with `dplyr` you can do `coalesce(x, y)`

Answer (score 1):

As Ben suggested, you can use `coalesce()`. Based on your present sample data, I did the following. For each pair of columns in a same position in `x` and `y`, I used `coalesce()` and created a vector. I converted the result of `sapply()` to a data frame and added `worker_ID` in the end. Note that I used `as.numeric()` for `Var_3`. I am not sure how your data is like, but Var_3 in `x` can be logical rather than numeric. I made sure that Var_3 in `x` and Var_3 in 'y` are both numeric.

```
library(tidyverse)

sapply(2:ncol(x), function(whatever){
  coalesce(as.numeric(pull(x, whatever)),
           as.numeric(pull(y, whatever))) -> foo
  return(foo)
}) %>% 
as_tibble %>% 
bind_cols(work_ID = pull(x, 1), .)

#  A tibble: 2 x 4
#  work_ID    V1    V2    V3
#    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1       1    33    75    NA
#2       2    NA    46    66
```

**UPDATE**

Taking akrun's advice, I think the following code works well. `map_dfc()` loops through each column pair just as `sapply()` does. The good thing is that `map_dfc()` creates a data frame; no need to use `as_tibble()`.

```
map_dfc(2:ncol(x), ~ coalesce(as.numeric(pull(x, .x)),
                              as.numeric(pull(y, .x)))) %>% 
bind_cols(work_ID = pull(x, 1), .)
```

Comment: @akrun Hey akrun, thanks for your feedback. I had a look of `map` and thought the following is perhaps better. `map_dfc(2:ncol(x), ~ coalesce(as.numeric(pull(x, .x)), as.numeric(pull(y, .x)))) %>% bind_cols(work_ID = pull(x, 1), .)`. What do you think?

Comment: @akrun Thanks for taking your time and helping me brush up my skills again. I definitely need some catch up with latest development.